# How to test a "binary" or unset char*?

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

EDIT : some precisions that change much to the question condition have been added, please note that before judging answers.

I get an environment variable under a `const char*` form. The env var can be

- Unset (By unset I mean, if the env vars are for example taken from a batch environment, `set MyBinaryEnvVar=`)
- Set to 0
- Set to 1

The const char* form will consequently be

- ""
- "0"
- "1"

I would like to test it with a one liner, Unset and "0" failing the test and "1" passing it. So something like :

```
if(getEnvVar("MyBinaryEnvVar")) {dontWorry();}
else {beHappy();}
```

`getEnvVar` returns a const char* .

Tests have shown on VisualStudio 2010 that the three values for the envVar pass the test, so
if("") <==> if("0") <==> if("1") <==> TRUE

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B) ?

Comment: What exactly is "unset"? Empty string or something else?

Comment: @CookieOfFortune maybe, I don't know it's exact behavior on char* either

Comment: @jrok question updated

Comment: I think at least one general, useful info can be retained, it's that if of a non-null char* is true. A think I'll get several downs if I ask an up though :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `getEnvVar` can return NULL for unset values, you can't efficiently both check for NULL and compare a value in one line.

Assuming you'll do a lot of this and want a concise way of doing it, you could delegate both operations to a new function and call it as a one-liner:

```
bool isVarSet(const char* var)
{
    const char* val = getEnvVar("MyBinaryEnvVar");
    if (val != NULL && strcmp(val, "1") == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(isVarSet("MyBinaryEnvVar")) {dontWorry();}
else {beHappy();}
```

On the other hand, if `getEnvVar` returns an empty string `""` for unset values, you can simply do

```
if(strcmp(getEnvVar("MyBinaryEnvVar"), "1") == 0) {dontWorry();}
else {beHappy();}
```

Comment: Best answer for now.
For the second part, I can't use strcmp though

Comment: Validating your answer, I'll have to find an equivalent to strcmp.

Comment: @Kharski Glad the answer was helpful.  Can you confirm why you're unable to use `strcmp`?  It'd be trivial to write your own version if need-be but I'm struggling to think of company policies which could productively ban all use of the C standard library...

Comment: think no longer! Dassault Systemes, yes yes, the biggest French software editor. I'm quiting, tomorrow normally.
But I do have to say that generally banning all 3rd-party software does have a good rational behind it : you depend on someone else. They can change their licensing, break their code etc. Although I don't see why they can't just stick with an old version, in these cases, which is ok if the dependency has a very high chance of being flawless, as with the stdlib.
In practice though, a lot of stuff developped in-house is just not good, sometimes at all.

Comment: `strcmp` isn't really third party software though.  It comes as part of the C standard library, which itself is provided with your OS and/or compiler.  Your (soon former) employer must have either written their own OS+compiler which includes the standard library or be using third party versions which include a standard library implementation.  Put differently, if you can call `malloc` I'd have thought you'd be able to call `strcmp`

Comment: yeah sorry wrong explanation : stdlib functions are used but only by the team offering OS abstraction. Then we call these abstractions. This has sense for... abstraction reasons, I guess. The company (used to) support a very large amount of OSs, including AIX. Although then again I haven't checked it but probably stdlib compiles pretty much everywhere (I would imagine). Also the policy seems to be : "We do IT, but this is too dangerous for you. Use these macros and built-in-house stuff". Also, a lot of engineers are actually generalists or mechanical, not IT (especially historically)

Answer (score 3):

See `strcmp()` for string comparison. All values returned by `getenv()` are strings. All you need is an `if` statement.

Note that your logic misses the "other" case (when the value is truly unset (i.e. `getenv()` returning `NULL`) or it is something else than the 3 values above.

Comment: I'd recommend at least the more safe version `strncmp()` or to use `std::string` as the OP asks for [tag:c++].

Comment: I can't use strcmp (company restrictions)
My getenv deosn't return strings, but const char, as indicated.
I'm clarifying the Unset/null case in the question, thanks

Comment: @Kharski `const char*` is a C-style string.  Or did you mean `const char` (which would be an odd way of returning a single `char`)?

Comment: @simonc It is a C-style string. If you think I should retag to C rather than C++ please put a meta.SO link with the justification and I'll do.